# Can We use a small part out of Enyo's ilib package?

Tags: enyo

I have a small requirement to internationalize strings. Honestly the topic itself is so wide. but I only wish to use its `ResourceBundle` functionality where I only wish to include `strings.json` files for each language and use `$L("some key")` in my `enyo` app. Is it possible with minimum number of individual dependent javascript files ?

[This](http://enyojs.com/docs/latest/building-apps/localization.html) is what I am talking about. Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

The enyo-ilib package has 3 "sizes" of ilib in it. By default, you get the "standard" size which has a reasonable set of things that people might need in it like date formatting, number formatting, etc. What you want is the "core" size which includes only the resource bundle class and the string formatter plus all the classes they depend on like the locale class. In order to use the core size of ilib in your enyo app, you would do the following in your package.js file:

```
enyo.depends({
    "$lib/enyo-ilib/core-package.js",
    <other libraries>,
    ...
});
```

Then, set up a resources directory right beside where your index.html is:

```
index.html
resources/
  de/
    strings.json -- strings for German
  fr/
    strings.json -- strings for French
  etc.
```

Then you should be able to use $L without the memory footprint of the standard size of ilib.

Comment: I am getting an error which is taking to `glue.js 237 line`. Something to do with `ilib.indexOf(..)`

Comment: Oh man, you're right, sorry about that. Okay, I've fixed this for the next build of ilib, which will be in the next build of enyo-ilib. If you can't wait, the sources for ilib are available on sourceforge under the project name i18nlib. You can build it for yourself if you need to. Or just wait for the next build of enyo.

Comment: Okay, I can not wait till it gets built and released. So Please don't mind to tell me what files should I put in the `package.js` file to include in my dependency spec. (Along with `ilib/js/ilib-core-compiled.js`)

Comment: If you get a copy of [this file](https://sourceforge.net/p/i18nlib/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/js/src/util/jsutils.js), then you can put the path in your core-package.js file between the line that loads in ilib-dyn-core.js and the line that loads in enyo-ilib2.js. That should temporarily solve the problem.